# Change media default profile

Tags: onvif

Is that possible to change the default media profile manually?
I've checked out documentation:

[media onvif docs](https://www.onvif.org/specs/srv/media/ONVIF-Media-Service-Spec.pdf)

And due to the docs, "default profile" is chosen via device capabilities:

> Real-time video and audio streaming configurations are controlled
>   using media profiles. A media profile maps a video and/or audio source
>   to a video and/or an audio encoder, PTZ and analytics configurations.
>   An ONVIF compliant device supporting the media service presents
>   different available profiles depending on its capabilities (the set of
>   available profiles might change dynamically though).

1. Which profile will be chosen, if the couple of them fulfill the capabilities?
2. Can I change the default profile by onvif's media API? If not: How can I simulate capabilities' change?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're supposed to be able to get all disponible profiles from the camera and then use the wanted profile token in your requests. See [GetProfiles](https://www.onvif.org/ver20/media/wsdl/media.wsdl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested with several brands of cameras. They all have some 'default' profiles mostly a mainstream(high quality) and substream(low(er) quality). I found out that the order of the profiles on the devices are random but can be set manually with the device software interface. So if you want for example the mainstream first you can confige this on the device software. Then the next time you connect to the first available profile it will be the one of your choise.

Setting the profile after getting them through the media client (with GetProfiles) can be done as suggested by LoukMo's comment.